# Integration Testing Nodejs/Express/Mongoose with Jest/Supertest One Mongoose Model Saves, One Mongoose Model Doesn't

Tags: mongodb, express, jestjs, mongoose-schema, supertest

I use Postman and the ReactJS UI to call this registration execution and it works as I expect. Ironically, the Jest and Supertest integration tests do not produce expected results. When integration testing, the Profile is created and the User is not.

The architecture is pretty simple. MongoDB in a Docker container, and Node using nodemon in VSCode.

I have to be doing something wrong, I just can't spot what it is.

```
// The Integration Test __test__/users/../user.test.js

const app = require('../../app');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const User = require('../../src/models/User');
const Profile = require('../../src/models/Profile');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const request = require("supertest");

const {
    MONGO_URI,
    TEST_DB_NAME
} = process.env;
let DB_URI = MONGO_URI + TEST_DB_NAME;
let NAME = TEST_DB_NAME;

mongoose.connect(DB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    dbName: NAME
});

describe('User Integration Test', () => {
    // make sure app is imported without issues
    it('Has App Defined', () => {
        expect(app).toBeDefined();
    });

    let server;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        // Clear Test Data
        await User.deleteMany({});
        await Profile.deleteMany({});
        server = await app.listen(3001);
    });

    afterAll(async (done) => {
        // Clear Test Data
        await User.deleteMany({});
        await Profile.deleteMany({});
        // Close server
        await server.close(done);
    });

    describe('User route tests', () => {

        it('Can Register a User', async () => {
            const body = {
                "username": "User21",
                "email": "user21@user.com",
                "password": "123456",
                "avatar": "image.jpg"
            }
            await request(server)
                .post('/api/v1/users')
                .send(body)
                .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                .expect(200)
        });

});

// THE EXPRESS ROUTE in api/v1/users.js

const express = require('express');
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const router = express.Router();
const { UserService } = require('../../services');
const {
    check,
    validationResult
} = require('express-validator/check');

// @route   POST api/users
// @desc    Register User
// @access  Public
// @return  status message
router.post('/', [
    check('email', 'Please provide a valid email address').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Please enter a password with 6 or more characters').isLength({ min: 6 }),
    check('username', 'Username is Required.').not().isEmpty()
], async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        //--Validate
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                errors: errors.array()
            });
        }

        const message = await UserService.register(req.body);
        return res.status(200).json(message)

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});

// THE register METHOD found in ../../services/UserService.js

const register = async (data) => {
    try {

        // Destructure the data
        const {
            username,
            email,
            password,
            avatar
        } = data;

        // remove spaces from username and lcase it
        let user_name = username.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
        // Check if the username or email already exists
        await doesUserExist(user_name, email);
        // Create a new user 
        const token = uuidv4();
        user = new User({
            email: email.toLowerCase(),
            username: user_name,
            avatar: avatar,
            verifyEmailToken: token
        });

        // encrypt the password
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        // Save the user
        // (Works Unless Running Jest Integration Tests)
        await user.save(); 

        // Create and save an empty Profile for the new user
        profile = new Profile();
        profile.user = user;
        // (Always Works)
        await profile.save();

        // Send verification email
        await send(user, 'Verify Your Email', token, 'verify-email.html');

        return { message: 'User was registered successfully.' };


    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}

// Does user exist method found in ./UserService.js
const doesUserExist = async (username, email) => {

    // Check if user exists by email
    let message = await checkEmail(email);
    if (!message.email_available) {
        throw new Error('Email already exists');
    }
    // Check if user exists by username
    message = await checkUserName(username.toLowerCase())
    if (!message.username_available) {
        throw new Error('Username already exists');
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I call this code via the UI, Postman, or curl both the User and Profile are created, as expected.

When I run the Integration Test, npm run test:integration or npm test,
Only the Profile is created.

my package.json scripts:
"test": "jest",
"test:integration": "jest --testPathPattern integration.test",

Finally, no errors are reported anywhere. User simply isn't created.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of work and testing this issue I found that the afterAll() event was raise randomly. Sometimes after all the tests in the inner describe() ran and sometimes not. Of course, when afterAll() ran all Users where deleted from the data store.

If moved beforeAll() and AfterAll() to the inner describe(). This worked very well until I included other integration tests, like authorization, for example that also used the User table. I noticed that the test suites are not executed synchronously. As one test suit was blowing out the data in another test suite as the other test suite was executing.

I now set up a database per test suite. Clunky, wonky, hacky and wrong I know but I have to have move on. Does anyone know if you can control the synchronous and/or asynchronous behavior of Jest? Please don't suggest Mocha and/or Chai.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, where there appeared to be an intermittent race condition between seeding a document and then retrieving it.

I fixed it by running jest with the `--runInBand` flag.